# Values of the determinants $\det[(j-k)^m+\delta_{jk}]_{1\le j,k\le n}\ (m=1,2,3,\ldots)$

Tags: nt.number-theory, linear-algebra, polynomials, determinants, integer-sequences

For positive integers $m$ and $n$, let $D_m(n)$ denote the determinant $\det[(j-k)^m+\delta_{jk}]_{1\le j,k\le n}$, where the Kronecker delta $\delta_{jk}$ is $1$ or $0$ according as $j=k$ or not.

Recently, joint with my graduate student Han Wang, we proved in [arXiv:2206.12317](http://arxiv.org/abs/2206.12317) the identity
$$D_1(n)=1+\frac{n^2(n^2-1)}{12}\tag{1}$$
via eigenvalues. (See also [A079034](https://oeis.org/A079034) at OEIS.)
Based on my numerical computations, I conjectured that
$$\begin{align}D_2(n)&=1+\frac{n^2(n^2-1)}{1080}(n^5-5n^3-36n^2+4n+54)
\\&=\frac{(n^2-4)(n^2+2n+3)(n^5-2n^4-n^3-28n^2+60n-90)}{1080}\end{align}\tag{2}$$
and
$$\begin{align}D_3(n)=&1+\frac{n^2(n^2-1)}{672000}
\\&\times(n^{12}-19n^{10}+123n^8-337n^6+12376n^4-44144n^2+40000)\end{align}\tag{3}$$
(cf. [A355175](https://oeis.org/A355175) and [A355326](https://oeis.org/A355326) at OEIS). Note that the equation
$$x^5-2x^4-x^3-28x^2+60x-90=0$$
over $\mathbb Q$ is not solvable by radicals.

In view of $(1)-(3)$, I have the following general conjecture.

**Conjecture.** Let $m$ be any positive integer. Then $D_m(n)$ has the form
$1+n^2(n^2-1)P_m(n)$, where $P_m(n)$ is a polynomial in $n$ with rational number coefficients whose degree is $(m+1)^2-4$.

**QUESTION.** How to prove the formulas $(2)$ and $(3)$? Is the above general conjecture true?

Your comments are welcome!

Answer (score 6):

Edited to give a more complete (and cleaner) answer valid for all $m, n$. My original answer only applied for $n \geq m+1$, and only went through the proof for the case of $(x-y)^m$.

Say we have a polynomial $P(x, y) = \sum_{0 \leq a, b \leq m} c_{ab} x^a y^b$, and want to compute $\det(A + I)$ as a function of $n$, for $A = A(n) = (P(j, k))_{1 \leq j, k \leq n}$. Let $C = (c_{ab})_{0 \leq a, b \leq m}$, and let $V$ be the $n \times (m+1)$ matrix with columns $v_0, v_1, \dots, v_m$, where $v_d$ is the vector with $j$-th entry $j^d$ for $1 \leq j \leq n$. Then $v_a v_b^T$ is the $n \times n$ matrix with $(j, k)$-entry $j^a k^b$, so it follows that
$$A = \sum_{0 \leq a, b \leq m} c_{ab} v_a v_b^T = VCV^T$$
and thus by the [Weinstein-Aronszajn identity](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Weinstein%E2%80%93Aronszajn_identity)
$$\det(A + I) = \det(VCV^T + I) = \det(CV^TV + I) = \det(CS + I),$$
where $S = V^T V$. Note that $C$, $S$, and hence also $CS+I$ are $(m+1) \times (m+1)$.

Now, for $0 \leq a, b \leq m$, the $(a, b)$-entry of $S$ is $v_a^T v_b = s_{a+b}(n)$, where $s_d(n) := \sum_{j=1}^n j^d$. Since each $s_d(n)$ can be expressed as a polynomial in $n$ of degree $d+1$ (with rational coefficients), all entries of $CS+I$ are fixed polynomials in $n$, and thus the equation above expresses $\det(A+I)$ as a polynomial in $n$ (with rational coefficients when all $c_{ab}$ are rational).

In the case of $P(x, y) = (x-y)^m$, the resulting formula is
$$D_m(n) = \det\left((-1)^{m-a} \tbinom{m}{a} s_{m-a+b}(n) + \delta_{ab}\right)_{0 \leq a, b \leq m}.$$
In this case, the degree of each term in the expansion of the determinant is $(m+1)^2$, so $D_m(n)$ has degree at most $(m+1)^2$. The calculated polynomial agrees with yours for $m=1$ and $m=2$, I haven't checked $m=3$ yet.

Comment: I have checked your formula for $D_m(n)$. It is correct for all $m,n=1,\ldots,50$. Also, your formula supports my general conjecture.

Comment: Joint with my student Han Wang, we have shown that the formula  for $D_m(n)$ in the answer of or43 holds for all $m,n=1,2,3,\ldots$, and that for each positive integer $m$, $D_m(n)$ is indeed a polynomial in $n$ of degree $(m+1)^2$.

Comment: Great! I believe I now also have a proof that the corresponding formula works for all $n$, for a general polynomial in $j, k$. I would like to post it here at some point, if it's alright with you.

Comment: Okay, you may pose your solution. Are you interesting in writing a joint paper with us concerning my questions here?

Comment: Thank you, it's kind of you to offer, but I would rather not put my name on anything. If you're writing a paper on this, I don't want to get in the way, and I can post my solution once you're done.

Comment: Of course, you can pose your solution at once. If you don't want to write any paper about this, we will not do so either since you are the main contributor to the answer.

Comment: It's a pity that some good solutions at MathOverflow will never appear in any formal paper.